# Invalid parameter clf for estimator Pipeline in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, pca

Could anyone check problems with the following code?
Am I wrong in any steps in building my model?
I already added two 'clf__' to parameters.

```
clf=RandomForestClassifier()
pca = PCA()
pca_clf = make_pipeline(pca, clf) 


kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=22)



parameters = {'clf__n_estimators': [4, 6, 9], 'clf__max_features': ['log2', 
'sqrt','auto'],'clf__criterion': ['entropy', 'gini'], 'clf__max_depth': [2, 
 3, 5, 10], 'clf__min_samples_split': [2, 3, 5],
'clf__min_samples_leaf': [1,5,8] }

grid_RF=GridSearchCV(pca_clf,param_grid=parameters,
        scoring='accuracy',cv=kfold)
grid_RF = grid_RF.fit(X_train, y_train)
clf = grid_RF.best_estimator_
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
grid_RF.best_score_

cv_result = cross_val_score(clf,X_train,y_train, cv = kfold,scoring = 
"accuracy")

cv_result.mean()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are assuming the usage of `make_pipeline` in a wrong way. From [the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.make_pipeline.html):-

> This is a shorthand for the Pipeline constructor; it does not require,
>   and does not permit, naming the estimators. Instead, their names will
>   be set to the lowercase of their types automatically.

So that means that when you supply a PCA object, its name will be set as 'pca' (lowercase) and when you supply a RandomForestClassifier object to it, it will be named as 'randomforestclassifier', not 'clf' as you are thinking.

So now the parameter grid you have made is invalid, because it contains `clf__` and its not present in pipeline.

## Solution 1 :

Replace this line:

```
pca_clf = make_pipeline(pca, clf)
```

With

```
pca_clf = Pipeline([('pca', pca), ('clf', clf)])
```

## Solution 2 :

If you dont want to change the `pca_clf = make_pipeline(pca, clf)` line, then replace all the occurences of clf inside your `parameters` to 'randomforestclassifier' like this:

```
parameters = {'randomforestclassifier__n_estimators': [4, 6, 9], 
              'randomforestclassifier__max_features': ['log2', 'sqrt','auto'],
              'randomforestclassifier__criterion': ['entropy', 'gini'], 
              'randomforestclassifier__max_depth': [2, 3, 5, 10], 
              'randomforestclassifier__min_samples_split': [2, 3, 5],
              'randomforestclassifier__min_samples_leaf': [1,5,8] }
```

**Sidenote**: No need to do this in your code:

```
clf = grid_RF.best_estimator_
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

The `best_estimator_` will already be fitted with the whole data with best found params, so you calling `clf.fit()` is redundant.